# How to access the css resources in MVC specified in Area section?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I am unable to access CSS file which is located under MVC AREA section.

Here is the full path of the CSS file.

http://mywebsite/Areas/MVC/Resources/dist/css/custom.css

I tried to debug using firebug and it prints the following error message.

> The stylesheet
>   http://mywebsite/Areas/MVC/Resources/dist/css/custom.css was not
>   loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

**Although I have specified the text/css type in the link attribute.**

I am referring to the css file as below

```
<link href="~/Areas/MVC/Resources/dist/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I have also tried giving the absolute path but still no luck.

If we try to open the above link in browser it is opening correctly and showing CSS but it does not load in the application.
Also the js resouces and images are being loaded in the same folder by using the same path but not the CSS.

Comment: have you  tried like this href="../css/custom.css" ????

Comment: Use your browsers developer tools to see exactly what is being returned when the request for the css is made: it may be an error page hence the wrong content type.

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati yes I have tried using that path too but still same.

Comment: @Richard if I browse the file using developer tool the file shows empty. However when I copy the path and open it in the browser window it returns the css file.

Answer (score 0):

Try linking the css file in your main html file. Also, if your system is an user login system then, try linking the css file in that html file which does not require user login.

Comment: It is linked in layout and it doesn't require login to access as well.

Comment: try renaming your css file.